# Possible to access Matlab class properties without using reference to object?

Tags: matlab

Say I have a MatLab class called Room that has properties 'width' and 'height'.

Do I always have use this.width and this.height to refer to these properties when I am in a method belonging to the room class or is it possible to just refer to them as width and height when I am in a class method?

It seems very inefficient to have to always use this.{some_property} or obj.{some_property} to refer to these properties inside class methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would always refer to the properties as `obj.width` or `obj.height` within the class methods.

I think you're perhaps exaggerating the inefficiency here - if you're really worried about it, you can at least easily reduce the problem by 66%, by using the name `o` to refer to your object instead of `obj`.